# How to get sorted files by digit present at some part in its name string in SQLite DB Android

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, android-sqlite

**Query i added :**

```
 String query= "SELECT  * FROM " + GURBANI_TABLE+" where "+TYPE+"='"+type+
                "' order by "+FILE_NAME;
```

**Output returned:**

1. Kirtan (Vol **1**).mp3
2. Kirtan (Vol **10**).mp3
3. Kirtan (Vol **11**).mp3
4. ...

**But needed:**

1. Kirtan (Vol **1**).mp3
2. Kirtan (Vol **2**).mp3
3. Kirtan (Vol **3**).mp3
4. ...

Required to be sorted by Vol numbering. But not by alphabetical order.

Comment: Are all the rows like `Kirtan (Vol XXX).mp3` and the only difference is the number or there are rows with different prefix?

Comment: There are only digits between 1 to 100.

Comment: I asked if all the filename start with `Kirtan (Vol ` and the follows a number.

Comment: It can be any string at starting but (Vol {1-99} is the must.

Comment: Don't build SQL queries with string concatenation! See SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the substring of the column that starts after `'(Vol '` and add `0` so that it is converted to an integer and sort by that:

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM " + GURBANI_TABLE + " WHERE " + TYPE + " = ' " + type +
               "' ORDER BY " +
               "SUBSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", 1, INSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", '(Vol '))," +
               "SUBSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", INSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", '(Vol ') + LENGTH('(Vol ')) + 0";
```

But it would be better to write the query with `?` placeholders instead of concatenating variables:

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM " + GURBANI_TABLE + " WHERE " + TYPE + " = ? " +
              "ORDER BY " +
              "SUBSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", 1, INSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", '(Vol '))," +
              "SUBSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", INSTR(" + FILE_NAME + ", '(Vol ') + LENGTH('(Vol ')) + 0";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {type})
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=01b380219751de7286e82fba48b329af) in SQLite.